# How to achieve single call to database in my LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am working on my web API project.

I have this **Linq To Entity** row inside controller class:

```
SiteObject[] objects = await ObjectsRepository.Get().Where(x => x.SiteRegionId == regionId).ToArrayAsync();

return Ok(objects.Select(x => new ObjectBreif
    {
        IsServiceable = Context.InspectionReview.Any(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id && i.IsNormal == false) ? false : Context.InspectionReview.Any(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id) ? true : (bool?)null 
    })
```

I want to create something more effective then the row above,not to do twice database call.

If in InspectionReview table exist **at least** one row that satisfy this 
conditions:

```
ObjectId = 5 AND  IsNormal = false
```

I need  to set `IsServiceable` to `false` otherwise, I need to check if in InspectionReview table exist row with this condition:

```
 ObjectId = 5
```

if it is, `IsServiceable` have to get `true` otherwise, `null`.

I achieved this by using a line of code above.But as you can see it is not effective,because I access database twice.

Any idea any idea how can I achieve the same result only with one call to database in one row I don't want to create additional function for this propose or extra rows as I want the code to stay elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to know what `objects` in your code is, but anyway, here you go:

With subquery

```
var result =
    from x in objects
    let AnyNormal = db.InspectionReview.Where(r => r.ObjectId == x.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty().Min(r => r == null ? (int?)null : r.IsNormal ? 1 : 0)
    select new ObjectBreif
    {
        IsServiceable = AnyNormal == null ? (bool?)null : AnyNormal == 1
    };
```

or with left outer join

```
var result =
    from x in objects
    join r in db.InspectionReview on x.Id equals r.ObjectId into g
    let AnyNormal = g.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(r => r == null ? (int?)null : r.IsNormal ? 1 : 0)
    select new ObjectBreif
    {
        IsServiceable = AnyNormal == null ? (bool?)null : AnyNormal == 1
    };
```

**Update:**: Now when you updated the code snippet, if `ObjectsRepository.Get` returns `IQueryable<SiteObject>` from the db (w/o materializing it in advance), it might be better to combine both queries into a single one like this

```
var result =
    from x in ObjectsRepository.Get() where x.SiteRegionId == regionId
    join r in db.InspectionReview on x.Id equals r.ObjectId into g
    let AnyNormal = g.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(r => r == null ? (int?)null : r.IsNormal ? 1 : 0)
    select new ObjectBreif
    {
        IsServiceable = AnyNormal == null ? (bool?)null : AnyNormal == 1
    };
```

because it would produce a single db query while all others will execute (ok, single, not twice as in the original) query **per each item** in the `objects` array.

Comment: @Michael in your code snippet `return Ok(objects.Select...`

Comment: Yeah,sorry.I have entity called SiteObject the objects are arrays of type SiteObject.

Comment: I made some changes in my example above

Comment: @Michael Ok, so it's not a db table. If the list(array) contains relatively small numebr of items, then query variants with `objects.Contains` might perform better, because it will allow generating a single db query with `IN (..)` clause. Or if you don't need the array for something else, combining both queries in a single one (in case `ObjectsRepository.Get` is IQueryable.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var items = Context.InspectionReview.Where(i => i.ObjectID == x.id).ToList();
bool? IsServicable = (items.length == 0) ? 
                     (bool?)null : !(items.Any(i => i.IsNormal == false));
```

Comment: Not bad, but why return a list from the database when only one row is needed? If there are many rows with the same ObjectID, this solution would fetch all of them as an unindexed list, then iterate over them.

Comment: @mikeagg Valid point. It would depend on how many records that would be. If relatively low, then the performance trade-off with ordering them first would be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: since `ObjectId` is not unique:

```
var grouped = (from ir in Context.InspectionReview
group ir by ir.ObjectId into g
select new {
              ObjectId = g.Key, 
              FalsePresent = g.Any(gg=>gg.IsNormal == false)}).FirstOrDefault();

if(grouped == null) return (bool?)null;
return !grouped.FalsePresent;
```

Comment: ObjectId is not primery key

Comment: Any idea how can I make it in one row?

Answer (score 1):

Filter by `ObjectID` first, then preferentially select those where `IsNormal` is false:

```
var first = Context.InspectionReview
    .Where(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id)
    .OrderBy(i => IsNormal)
    .FirstOrDefault();
bool? IsServiceable = (first == null) ? (bool?)null : first.IsNormal;
```

Comment: When it returns false?

Comment: @Michael Since he's checking that first isn't null, the first.IsNormal would be true if a true record existed due to the OrderBy clause, and false otherwise.